# How do I access Rails environment variables in a webpacker bundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

Is it possible to access my Rails environment variables from webpacker bundles? I know I can use dotenv, but the project uses Figaro and I would prefer not to change that. I would really like to pass the env vars from Rails to webpacker during compilation of the bundles.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. If you put your `.env` file in `config/webpack` and then add this code to your `config/webpack/application.js` file, you should be good:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config({path: __dirname + '/.env'})

environment.plugins.insert(
    "Environment",
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(process.env)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using webpacker `5.4.3` and I use [dotenv-webpack](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) to solve this problem.

```
yarn add -D dotenv-webpack
```

Put the ".env*" files in your Rails project root directory, then edit environment.js:

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
environment.plugins.prepend('Dotenv', new Dotenv());

// your other settings...

module.exports = environment
```

Then you can access the environments through `process.env`

```sh
# .env
ABC=123
```

```js
//packs/application.js
console.log(process.env.ABC)
// => 123
```